# LinkedIn - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, linkedin-api

we have several apps that were working a few days ago and today they are not able to log into **LinkedIn**

The error that we're getting is:

> org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem
>   while creating a connection to the remote service.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Does anyone know why this is happening and how could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PKIX** stands for "**`Public Key Infrastructure eXchange`**." The most likely cause of this is that the server you are connecting to changed their SSL certificate to chain to something your system doesn't know.

Upgrading your JDK may fix the issue by nature of trusting the newer root certificate. Otherwise, you can extract the root from the certificate chain provided or find it another way, and add it to your trust store.